# Big data methods: Iterative (chunk-wise) computation of data moments

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, hdf5

I'm having data in the terabytes. Therefore, standard `pandas` and `numpy` procedures (`group-by`, `mean`, `histogram` etc.) will not work when I can't load in all the data at the same time.

My data will come from [`pandas.HDFStore.select`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.HDFStore.select.html) which can return an iterator with chunks of variable chunk-size.

Now all I need is methods on how to calculate moments of the data based on iterative approaches.

The **expected value** is straight-forward:

```
n, mean = 0, 0
for chunk in iterator:
    nCurrent = len(chunk)
    meanCurrent = chunk['variable'].mean()
    mean = (n * mean + nCurrent * meanCurrent)/(n + nCurrent)
    n += nCurrent
```

However it's not clear what the general approach is. How would I do this for **higher-order moments**?

Also, I am interested in plotting the distribution. Say I decide to go for a **histogram**. Without knowing the limits of the distribution at the beginning, it's hard to create the bins. Do I first need to iterate once through the whole distribution to get the min and max, and then create bins and start counting? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

for the average (`mean`) it can be done like this:

```
i, cumsum = 0
for chunk in store.select('key', chunksize=N):
    cumsum += chunk['variable'].sum()
    i += len(chunk)

my_mean = cumsum / i
```

As a *general* approach i would go for an Apache Spark on Hadoop Cluster if you have to work with terabytes of data